# How do I keep sorting order while paging in gridView?

Tags: c#, sorting, gridview, ascx

I am displaying information using gridView.  It works absolutely perfect for me except for one detail.  If the user sorts a column and then clicks to go to another page then the sorting is lost.  Basically I need the sorting to persist while paging occurs, any help would be most appreciated.  Here is the code I have:

```
public partial class DynamicGridView : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (_selectCmd != string.Empty)
            BindData();
    }

    private void BindData()
    {
        DataTable dt;
        if (ViewState[gridView.ClientID + "datatable"] == null || (string)ViewState[gridView.ClientID + "selectCommand"] != _selectCmd)
        {
            ViewState[gridView.ClientID + "selectCommand"] = _selectCmd;
            dt = Classes.SQL.GetDataTable(_selectCmd);

            if (dt != null)
            {
                ViewState[gridView.ClientID + "datatable"] = dt;
                if (dt.Columns.Count != gridView.Columns.Count)
                {
                    gridView.Columns.Clear();
                    foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns)
                        AddBoundField(column);
                }
            }
        }
        else
            dt = (DataTable)ViewState[gridView.ClientID + "datatable"];

        gridView.DataSource = dt;
        gridView.DataBind();
    }

    private void AddBoundField(DataColumn column)
    {
        BoundField field = new BoundField();
        HandleCustomDataFormatting(ref field, column);
        field.DataField = column.ColumnName;
        field.HeaderText = column.ColumnName;
        field.ReadOnly = true;
        field.SortExpression = column.ColumnName;
        field.ControlStyle.ForeColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#333333");
        field.ItemStyle.Width = System.Web.UI.WebControls.Unit.Pixel(70);

        gridView.Columns.Add(field);
    }

    private void HandleCustomDataFormatting(ref BoundField field, DataColumn column)
    {
        if (column.DataType == typeof(System.DateTime))
            switch (column.ColumnName)
            {
                case "InvalidDate":
                case "NewCustomerValidated":
                case "ValidatedDate":
                    field.DataFormatString = "{0:d}";//exclude time info
                    break;
                default:
                    field.DataFormatString = "{0:g}";
                    break;
            }
    }

    private string GetSortDirection(string sortColumn)
    {
        string sortDirection = "ASC";
        string lastSortColumn = (string)ViewState[gridView.ClientID + "SortExpression"];

        if (lastSortColumn != null && lastSortColumn == sortColumn)
        {
            string lastDirection = (string)ViewState[gridView.ClientID + "SortDirection"];
            if (lastDirection != null && lastDirection == "ASC")
                sortDirection = "DESC";
        }
        ViewState[gridView.ClientID + "SortExpression"] = sortColumn;
        ViewState[gridView.ClientID + "SortDirection"] = sortDirection;

        return sortDirection;
    }

    private string _selectCmd = string.Empty;

    public string SelectCommand
    {
        set { _selectCmd = value; }
    }

    protected void GridView_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable dt = (DataTable)ViewState[gridView.ClientID + "datatable"];
        dt.DefaultView.Sort = e.SortExpression + " " + GetSortDirection(e.SortExpression);
        BindData();
    }

    protected void GridView_PageChange(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
    {
        gridView.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
        BindData();
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you storing the `DataTable` and the sql-command in `ViewState`? Don't do that. The former blows up the ViewState which slows down your application because it sends this viewstate back and forth between your client and your server. The latter is not safe, do you want that every user is able to see your sql-queries by decoding ViewState? Use `Session` if you need to persist it or reload it from database.

Comment: Also note for queries that would generate large amounts of data you may need to just fetch one page of data from the DB and then go and fetch a brand new page each time the page changes, if it's not practical to store the entire result set in `Session`.

Comment: Tim, This application is for "in-house" use only on a local intranet.  Furthermore it will be used by a handful of people so I am not too worried about them seeing the SQL queries.  I do agree with you however on all points you made. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to bind on each page load.

```
if (_selectCmd != string.Empty)
    if(!IsPostBack)
            BindData();
```

Also, be carefull what you put in the ViewState, it's not good practice to put the sql query.

Answer (score 0):

This approach has worked for me.

You can set up a couple variables to be something like this:

```
protected string SortColummn 
{
    get { return ViewState["SortColumn"].ToString(); }
    set { ViewState["SortColumn"] = value; }
}
protected string SortDirection 
{
    get { return ViewState["SortDirection"].ToString(); }
    set { ViewState["SortDirection"] = value; }
}
```

Set up default values for these in Page_Load in an "if (!Page.IsPostBack)" block. Then, in GridView_Sorting, set these two variables based on e.SortExpression. 
Finally, in BindData(), set dt.DefaultView.Sort based on these two variables.

Comment: One thing to note would be that the above comments about using Session vs. ViewState are accurate, but since Chris has said that he's not worried about these issues, I wrote my solution using viewstate.